# Getting an error day of month must be between 1 and last day of month

Tags: sql, oracle

HiAll,
  i am getting an error

> ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month
>   01847. 00000 -  "day of month must be between 1 and last day of month"

please suggest on this, below is sample i used in my query

```
when ((
   (( x.DailyKMUsage * (trunc(x.std)-trunc(x.ced)) ))
   / case when x.ckm <= 0 then 1 else x.ckm end
   )*100 ) > 0
then (((
   (( x.DailyKMUsage * (trunc(x.std)-trunc(x.ced)) ))
   / case when x.ckm <= 0 then 1 else x.ckm end
   )*100 )|| '% Over Utilised')
when ((
   (( x.DailyKMUsage * (trunc(x.std)-trunc(x.ced)) ))
   / case when x.ckm <= 0 then 1 else x.ckm end
   )*100 ) < 0
then (((
   (( x.DailyKMUsage * (trunc(x.std)-trunc(x.ced)) ))
   / case when x.ckm <= 0 then 1 else x.ckm end
   )*100 )|| '% Under Utilised')
```

Comment: Sounds as if `std` and `ced` were incorrectly defined as `varchar` columns and not dates and the implicit date format doesn't match the format stored in those columns.

Comment: no all are date columns only except Dailykmusage and ckm

Comment: Then the error must be in a different part of the query.

Comment: I am using union the first part of union is running fine when i run that separately once i joined with this giving an error

Comment: and when you run just this part of the union, does that work? Try running the union parts separately and carefully inspect the column-types returned (blind guess: you are forcing a non-date column into a date type)